# How can check if all instances of the class have finished?

Tags: php

1) In order to parallelize some work, I am instantiating multiple instances of the same class.

2) I can only create 5 objects at the same time before I can instantiate the next batch of 5.

That is where I am getting stuck. **How can I create a loop which would wait long enough before those 1st 5 objects are closed and then instantiate another batch of 5 instances?**

One option seems to be to create a global $counter in the __constructor and decrease it when each instance finishes, so when I start with global $counter = 5 I can proceed when $counter = 0 however isn't there a simpler solution?

**How can I quickly check if all instances of the class_x have finished ?**

Thank for help.

Comment: First you need to define what "finished" means.

Comment: ...each instance is connecting to a different database and can fetch variable number of records (hence different execution times for each instance). so "finished" means that the object has connected to the database, got records, closed the connection and destructed.

Comment: So then why not have the instance tell some other object that it's finished?

Comment: ....you mean like putting something at the end of the object i.e.: my above reference counter? Isn't there a easier solution on the actual class level? Something like a function to check for # of instances ?

Comment: Most languages don't burden themselves with this additional accounting.

Answer (score 0):

You could build yourself such a system with static properties. 
But it's not much different than using global vars.

Check the example:

```
class Worker
{

    public static $nrInstances = 0;
    public static $maxInstances = 2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (self::$nrInstances >= self::$maxInstances) {
            throw new Exception('No more instances allowed');
        }
        self::$nrInstances++;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        self::$nrInstances--;
    }

}


try {
    $worker1 = new Worker();
    var_dump(Worker::$nrInstances);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}

try {
    $worker2 = new Worker();
    var_dump(Worker::$nrInstances);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}

try {
    $worker3 = new Worker();
    var_dump(Worker::$nrInstances);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}

unset($worker1);
var_dump(Worker::$nrInstances);

unset($worker2);
var_dump(Worker::$nrInstances);

// output: int(1) int(2) int(1) int(0)
```

Comment: ... I am trying it but cannot make it work for me since I cannot destruct the instance if $nrInstances is larger than 2, I need it to wait until $nrInstances drops below 2....  Will keep u posted.

Comment: since PHP has no multithreading implemented I doubt that you will get any speed advantage with this method. For "real" parallel processing look at following post: [http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/parallel-processing-in-php/](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/parallel-processing-in-php/)

Comment: ..thanks, I read the same thing before. Since each instantiated object only executes a stored procedure on the local MSSQL the threading is actually done on the DB level (worker threads)... At least that's how I believe it would work. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ok it could work if you really use `mysqli_query(string query, MYSQLI_ASYNC))` and `mysqli_poll()` but I never used it before..

Comment: ..I missed that you work with mssql, I don't know if there is a asynchronous function.

Comment: ...actually I am using "ADODB" for MS SQL. Always something new to learn :)

Comment: it seems like mysqli is the only db api that support async operations. how to run mssql in parallel is a little beyond this thread...

Comment: perhaps one interesting link where he use the "curl method" to parallelize db queries: [http://gonzalo123.com/2010/10/11/speed-up-php-scripts-with-asynchronous-database-queries/](http://gonzalo123.com/2010/10/11/speed-up-php-scripts-with-asynchronous-database-queries/)